# How to store different kind of datas in single bucket in couchbase

Tags: couchbase

I want to store the diff kind of data in same bucket in Couchbase, am googled its suggest doc_type and type parameter , but i don't know how i implement that one in my data,I tried below code but i don't know how to do that?

i didn't seen any example,any help will be appreciate,

```
JsonObject doc = JsonObject.fromJson(consumerRecord.value().toString());
             String id=consumerRecord.key().toString();
             bucket.upsert(JsonDocument.create(id, doc));
```

Comment: I removed `spring-kafka` tag from your quesiton since there is really nothing about Kafka at all. Please, be careful choosing tag for your questions.

Comment: @ArtemBilan actually am consumed the data from Kafka using kafkalistener and using consumer record to write into couchbase

Comment: OK. But the issue still doesn't sound like related to Spring for Apache Kafka. Even if you use Kafka it doesn't mean that you need to include `spring-kafka`. Really don't see any relevance for that project. Sorry, if I miss something in your context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couchbase buckets store documents of any kind. You don't have to do anything special. As long as it's valid JSON, it can be stored in a Couchbase bucket.

Now, what you might want is some way to differentiate between different types of documents (for querying purposes, for instance). So, you can put a "type" field (or docType or whatever you'd like) as a kind of 'marker' value. You can see examples of this in the [built-in travel-sample bucket](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/manage/manage-settings/install-sample-buckets.html). For instance, look at the **airline_10** and the **route_10000** documents:

```
airline_10
{
  "callsign": "MILE-AIR",
  "country": "United States",
  "iata": "Q5",
  "icao": "MLA",
  "id": 10,
  "name": "40-Mile Air",
  "type": "airline"
}

route_10000
{
  "airline": "AF",
  "airlineid": "airline_137",
  "destinationairport": "MRS",
  "distance": 2881.617376098415,
  "equipment": "320",
  "id": 10000,
  "schedule": [ ... ],
  "sourceairport": "TLV",
  "stops": 0,
  "type": "route"
}
```

Notice that one has a type of "airline", the other has a type of "route". An example of a query to find routes:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM `travel-sample` t
WHERE t.type = 'route'
LIMIT 10
```

This is *one* way to differentiate documents. Also notice that the keys are constructed semantically, so they could also be used. Neither of these are a requirement, so it really depends on how you plan to access documents.

Comment: Whatever u said is correct but my question is I need to put that Type parameter in my json or its predefined ??

Comment: To Couchbase, "type" is just another field, there's nothing special about it. When you store a document, you can choose to store any fields you want (e.g. firstName, lastName, type, phoneNumber, etc). There is no schema to follow, Couchbase will not force you to make a type field. If you want one, you'll have to add it alongside the other data.

Comment: Note that Couchbase also supports storing arbitrary items such as serialized Java or Avro.  This is done through a transcoder interface.  JSON gives you more abilities to process the data, but you can process metadata even if it's non-JSON.